# how can I set my datalist's datasource to datatable in run time

Tags: asp.net

I have two data lists in my page and one of them is nested in the other one.
I would like to give their data sources in run time during page load event, but my inner data list doesn't show the value of the data table and I don't know how to set my inner data lists data source to data table in run time.

I have searched a lot about it but I couldn't find useful information. 
Please help me.

In the page I would like to show which user bought which products, show the quantity and price of each product and show some information about paid index. Like index number or index bank name.
The problem is, for one index number I can have several products. For showing the related products to each index number I used nested data list.
In my first data list now my outer (parent) data list can show the information but the inner data list which should show the products information does not show any thing.

I really need help

This is my code:

```
  <asp:DataList ID="outerDataLiat" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" 
            BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid"    BorderWidth="3px" 
            CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both"  DataKeyField="idfromIndex" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC"  />;
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="White" />
        <ItemTemplate />           
    <fieldset>

    <legend&gt>customer information&lt</legend&gt>
    <table style="width: 100%;"/>
     <tr>
      <td>
     &nbsp;customer code:
    </td>
     <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("idFromUsers") %>'</asp:Label>
             </td>;

                 <td>
                    &nbsp;telephone:
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("user_phone") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp; customer name :
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("user_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;cellphone number:
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("user_cellphone") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp; customer familly name :
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("user_familly") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;email :
                </td>
                <td>
                   &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("user_email") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Index Information</legend>
      <table style="width: 100%;">
          <asp:Label ID="hiddenLable" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("idfromIndex") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;Index number :
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IndexNO") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;date of index :
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;bank name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("bankName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>purchased products</legend>
    <asp:DataList ID="innerDataLiat" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" 
            BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" 
            CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both" OnItemDataBound="DataList2_ItemDataBound"  >
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC"  />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="White" />
        <ItemTemplate >
        <table style="width: 100%;" id="tbl1"></table>
       <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;product name :
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;quantity:
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;unit price of each product :
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>
               <td>
                    &nbsp;Total Amount:
                </td>
                <td>
                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
                   </ItemTemplate> 

        </asp:DataList>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset><legend>shopping cart Information</legend>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td >
                    &nbsp;Total quantity :
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>
              <td>
                    &nbsp;total amount of shopping cart:
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> &nbsp;date of shopping :</td>
            <td dir="rtl">&nbsp<asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("orderDate") %>'  /></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        </fieldset>


          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="confirm">confirm</asp:LinkButton>
          &nbsp;
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="notconfirm">not confirm</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>

            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

        </asp:DataList>


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        getDistinctOrderId();
        doPaging();
    }     
 }
private void getDistinctOrderId()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mobile_storeConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = myConnection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT min(id), [idfromIndex] FROM Orders WHERE [idfromIndex] IN(SELECT DISTINCT [idfromIndex] FROM Orders) GROUP BY [idfromIndex] ";
    DataView MyDv = new DataView();

    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        MyDv = dt.DefaultView;
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; MyDv.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == MyDv.Count - 1)
            {
                distinctList += MyDv[i][0].ToString();
            }
            else
                distinctList += MyDv[i][0].ToString() + ",";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception EXP)
    {
    }
    finally
    { myConnection.Close(); }
}
 public DataTable getTheData()
 {

 DataSet DS = new DataSet();
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter objSQLAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select idfromIndex,user_name,user_email,indexNO,bankName,Ispay,user_familly,user_cellphone,orderDate,user_phone,idFromUsers,orderId from factors where orderId IN (" + distinctList + ")", myConnection); objSQLAdapter.Fill(DS, "mobile_store");

    return DS.Tables[0];
 }

  void doPaging()
  {
    //DataTable mydatatable = 
    pagedData.DataSource = getTheData().DefaultView;
    pagedData.AllowPaging = true;
    pagedData.PageSize = 4;

 /* 
 ...
   here I wrote some code to make my outer datalist pagable
 ...
*/


    outerDataLiat.DataSource = pagedData;
    outerDataLiat.DataBind();

}

  protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
 {
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("hiddenLable");
        string idfromindex = lbl.Text;
        DataList lst2 = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("innerDataLiat");
        SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource();
        DataTable mydt = new DataTable();

        dataset t = setinnerDataList(idfromindex);
        tb2 = t;
        int sumqty = 0;
        double sumprice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; t.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            sumprice += Convert.ToDouble(t.Rows[i]["p_price"]) * Convert.ToInt32(t.Rows[i]["qty"]);
             sumqty += Convert.ToInt32(t.Rows[i]["qty"]);
        }
        Label lbl14 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label14");
        lbl14.Text = sumqty.ToString();
        Label lbl15 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label15");
        lbl15.Text = sumprice.ToString();

          Label pname = (Label)lst2.FindControl("pname");
        Label qty = (Label)lst2.FindControl("qty");
        Label price = (Label)lst2.FindControl("unit_price");
        DataRow[] dr = t.Tables[0].Select("idfromIndex = '" + idfromindex + "'");//new DataRow[t.Tables[0].Rows.Count]; //=  //This will select all rows where the Name Column has value MAK
        for (int i = 0; i < t.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dr[i] = t.Tables[0].Rows[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dr.Length; i++)
        {
            pname.Text = dr[i]["pname"].ToString();
            price.Text = dr[i]["p_price"].ToString();
            qty.Text = dr[i]["qty"].ToString();
        }

    }
}

  private dataset setinnerDataList(string idfromindex)
 {

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mobile_storeConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = myConnection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [pname], [p_price], [idfromIndex], [qty] FROM [factors] WHERE ([idfromIndex] = " + idfromindex + ") ";
    DataView MyDv = new DataView();
    dataset dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        dt.Load(dr);
        dr.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception EXP)
    {


    }
    finally
    { myConnection.Close(); }

    return dt;
 }</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thank you AYK for your help,  it Worked when I changed it this way:

```
    protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
   {
   if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        DataList dls1 = (DataList)sender;
        Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("hiddenLable");
        string idfromindex = lbl.Text;
        DataList lst2 = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("innerDataLiat");
        Panel pnl = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("Panel1");           
         t = setinnerDataList(idfromindex);
        int sumqty = 0;
        double sumprice = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < t.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            sumprice += Convert.ToDouble(t.Tables[0].Rows[i]["p_price"]) * Convert.ToInt32(t.Tables[0].Rows[i]["qty"]);
            sumqty += Convert.ToInt32(t.Tables[0].Rows[i]["qty"]);

        }
        Label lbl14 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label14");
        lbl14.Text = sumqty.ToString();
        Label lbl15 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label15");
        lbl15.Text = sumprice.ToString();
        lst2.DataSource = t;
        lst2.DataBind();
     }
    }  

       <asp:DataList ID="innerDataLiat" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" 
            BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
            CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Both" OnItemDataBound="DataList2_ItemDataBound"  >
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC"  />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="White" />
        <ItemTemplate >
        <table style="width: 100%;" ></table>
        <table style="width: 100%;" id="tbl1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;product name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="pname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;quantity :
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="qty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("qty") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;unit price:
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="unit_price" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("p_price") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </td>

            </tr>


        </table>
                   </ItemTemplate> 

        </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `DataList2_ItemDataBound` handler for `ItemDataBound` event of inner `DataList`. You will need to set control values for inner `DataList` as well, like you do in `DataList1_ItemDataBound` handler.

EDIT : Added more details below :

```
 protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
 {
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
       /*Algorithm to implement in this space :
           1. Find a Label control using FindControl.
           2. If label is not null, set its text.
           3. Do this for all controls which are inside your inner data list.
*/
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but can you show me how can I do that, I just know a little about asp.net,I become so thankfull if you show me

Comment: I dont have any control in my innerdatalist because it should show the information about the produucts which are related to the same index number and I dont know how many products each index has.so I want to set the innerdatalist's datasource to datatable at run time

Comment: even if you don't know how many products can be there for an index, you must know how it needs to be displayed, correct ? So like you have done for outer data list (i.e. define the layout of information to be displayed) you should place controls inside inner data list and bind values to it at runtime under ItemDataBound event as demonstrated in my answer above.

Comment: I added the table to my innerdatalist(you can see in my code) but my problem is I dont know how can i get the value of each table row in my datatable and put it in the table cell of table which I defined in innerdatalist

Comment: I add some code to my DataList1_ItemDataBound event,I edited my code you can see it; but it gives me this error:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for this line: pname.Text = dr[i]["pname"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement ***OnItemDataBound*** method for **outer DataList** so that you can assign **dataSource to inner DataList**

```
<asp:DataList ID="outerDataList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="outerRep_ItemDataBound">
```

and in code you have to do this

```
protected void outerRep_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
            DataList innerDataList = e.Item.FindControl("innerDataList") as DataList;
            innerDataList.DataSource = drv.CreateChildView("CategoriesRelation");
            innerDataList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

For more details you can find working example here [Nested DataList](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/nested-datalist-in-Asp-Net/)

Hope this will help you out.